# Can someone identify the bibliography style in this paper?

Tags: bibtex

I really love the citation and bibliography style in this paper: http://www.aaai.org/Papers/IJCAI/2007/IJCAI07-243.pdf but can't find the style; the aaai one [itself](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php) (which I thought it might be) doesn't seem to have the square brackets in the bibliography.

Comment: Welcome on [tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about). Did you consider to mail the authors themselves? They will know the answer.

Comment: I wanted to pick the brains of the community first in case someone already knew

Comment: author of your example might have [tweaked](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php) the [AAAI authors toolkit version](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/AuthorKit.zip). @DominikusK meta welcome toolkit is [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [`named`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/named) style.

Given the location of the example pdf, you can find a template for the document [here](http://ijcai13.org/files/ijcai13.zip). Using this template with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ijcai13}

\begin{document}
\cite{StGu92,MuBeBoRo99}
\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: sample output]

If you only want to use the citation/referencing part of the template, use it with

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\leftcite{\@up[}\def\rightcite{\@up]}

\def\cite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{\def\@thisauthor{##1}%
             \ifx \@lastauthor \@thisauthor \relax \else##1, \fi ##2}\@icite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@icite}

\def\citeauthor{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1}\@nbcite}
\def\citeyear{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@nbcite}

% internal macro for citations with [] and with breaks between citations
% used in \cite and \shortcite
\def\@icite{\leavevmode\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
 \def\@cite##1##2{\leftcite\nobreak\hskip 0in{##1\if@tempswa , ##2\fi}\rightcite}%
 \@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@citex}{\@tempswafalse\@citex[]}}
% internal macro for citations without [] and with no breaks
% used in \citeauthor and \citeyear
\def\@nbcite{\leavevmode\def\@citeseppen{1000}%
 \def\@cite##1##2{{##1\if@tempswa , ##2\fi}}%
 \@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@citex}{\@tempswafalse\@citex[]}}

% don't box citations, separate with ; and a space
% also, make the penalty between citations a parameter, 
% it may be a good place to break
\def\@citex[#1]#2{%
  \def\@lastauthor{}\def\@citea{}%
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{;\penalty\@citeseppen\ }%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\def\@thisauthor{}{\bf ?}\@warning
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
     {\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}\let\@lastauthor\@thisauthor}}{#1}}

% raise the brackets in bibliography labels
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}\@up{[}#1\@up{]}\hfill}

\def\@up#1{\leavevmode\raise.2ex\hbox{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{GhJaEn02,Ca04,BaNi94}
\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image: second sample output]

Comment: I thought that too, but that also doesn't have the square brackets

Comment: @Matuku It does when used as requested.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the additional instructions. It's very close now but in the paper multiple citations are separated by a semi-colon. Where in the bst would this be so I can change it?

Comment: @Matuku: The comma is set by LaTeX and not BibTeX.