# Why do I get "! Undefined control sequence" in bbl from very simple example?

Tags: bibtex

I am getting a very unexpected error message from a simple bibliography example.

I have a .tex and a .bib files:

test.tex:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

This is a citation: \cite{pearl88probabilistic}.

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{b}
\end{document}
```

b.bib:

```
@BOOK{pearl88probabilistic,
  AUTHOR = {J. Pearl},
  YEAR = {1988},
  title = {Probabilistic reasoning in intelligent systems: networks of plausible inference},
  PUBLISHER = {Morgan Kaufmann, San Mateo (Calif.)},
}
```

Then I run (using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows):

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test
pdflatex test
```

and get an error:

```
("C:\dir\test.bbl"
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \citeauthoryear
                                    {Pearl}{1988}
l.3 ...horyear{Pearl}{1988}]{pearl88probabilistic}
```

Using `latex` instead of `pdflatex`, or using a different bibtex entry, produces the same error.

Here's the offending line in test.bbl:

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Pearl}{1988}]{pearl88probabilistic}
```

Why am I getting this error message, given that the .tex and .bib inputs seem fine?

Here's the full (but cleaned up) trace of what I did (I replaced my user's directory by "dir"):

```
C:\dir>pdflatex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode

LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> (...)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
No file test.aux.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `pearl88probabilistic' on page 1 undefined on input lin
e 6.

No file test.bbl.
[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
("C:\dir\test.aux")

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 22197 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

C:\dir>bibtex test
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: named.bst
Database file #1: bib.bib

C:\dir>pdflatex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode

("C:\dir\test.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> (...)("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\dir\test.aux")

LaTeX Warning: Citation `pearl88probabilistic' on page 1 undefined on input lin
e 6.


("C:\dir\test.bbl"
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \citeauthoryear
                                    {Pearl}{1988}
l.3 ...horyear{Pearl}{1988}]{pearl88probabilistic}
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the `named` biblio style. Try the solution from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106875/117534

Comment: Why not consider using the `natbib` package instead? Also, welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks! Other styles produce the same error, but I will look into those solutions.

Comment: Ok, I checked and this is not because of `named`. I will look into natbib, but I would love to understand why this error is happening in such a simple example.

Comment: When an error occurs with a bibliography one often has to delete both the `aux` file as well as the `bbl` file, in order to clear the error from Latex's residual memory.

Comment: It absolutely is because of `named`. The style itself says you need to define commands like `\citeauthoryear` in order to use it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The hint is found in `named.bst`, which contains near the top of the file:

```
% The LaTeX style has to have the following (or similar)
%     \let\@internalcite\cite
%     \def\cite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}\@internalcite}
%     \def\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1{##2}\@internalcite}
%     \def\@biblabel#1{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}[#1]\hfill}
% which makes \shortcite the macro for short citations.
```

So you should follow the advice:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
%
@BOOK{pearl88probabilistic,
  AUTHOR = {J. Pearl},
  YEAR = {1988},
  title = {Probabilistic reasoning in intelligent systems: networks of plausible inference},
  PUBLISHER = {Morgan Kaufmann, San Mateo (Calif.)},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
    \let\@internalcite\cite
    \def\cite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}\@internalcite}
    \def\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1{##2}\@internalcite}
    \def\@biblabel#1{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1, ##2}[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a citation: \cite{pearl88probabilistic}.

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

If I don't follow the advice, I get your error. If I define the commands as suggested, I do not.

Comment: Note also that the header of `named.bst`, which references `LaTeX 2.09`(!!) also states `There are undoubtably bugs in this style.`  I'd be inclined to find something a little more modern to use if creating a new project in 2017....

Comment: Thanks. The reason I thought 'named' was not the problem is that there was a second problem with another package that generated problems even with plain and alpha.
By "more modern", what do you mean? natlib?

Comment: Yes, `natbib` or `biblatex` are the two most popular LaTeX packages for bibliographies, which means, among other things, people will have experience debugging them if need be and have an interest in doing so. But nearly every package or `bst` will be more modern than one designed for LaTeX 2.09.

Comment: Sad but true, embedding the bibliography inside the .tex solves this problem.

Answer (score 6):

In line with @Troy's suggestion, something like this?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}



\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{named}



\begin{document}

This is a citation: \citet{pearl88probabilistic}.

\bibliography{b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{named}

Comment: Good it solves my citation issue:
Before:
`\begin{document}

    This is a citation: \citet{pearl88probabilistic}.

    \bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{b}
\end{document}

After:
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{named}



\begin{document}

This is a citation: \citet{pearl88probabilistic}.

\bibliography{b}
\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

Good it solves my citation issue:

Before (error):

```
\begin{document}

This is a citation: \citet{pearl88probabilistic}.

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{b}

\end{document}
```

After (no error):

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{named}

\begin{document}

This is a citation: \citet{pearl88probabilistic}.

\bibliography{b}

\end{document}
```